# How to access -ldl in cross compiler in SDK

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors, sdk, linker

i am using Xilinx SDK with cross compiler as `aarch64-none-elf-gcc`
i am loading a shared library in my program and i am getting error as

```
Building target: fsbl.elf
Invoking: ARM v8 gcc linker
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -L"/proj/ssw_xhd/boot/balakrish/workspace/hello_world/Debug" -Lwrk/released/2017.3/GA/2017.3_1005_1/installs/lin64/SDK/2017.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-none/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-elf/6.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-elf/bin/ld -Wl,-T -Wl,../src/lscript.ld -L../../fsbl_bsp/psu_cortexa53_0/lib -o "fsbl.elf"  ./src/psu_init.o ./src/xfsbl_authentication.o ./src/xfsbl_board.o ./src/xfsbl_bs.o ./src/xfsbl_csu_dma.o ./src/xfsbl_dfu_util.o ./src/xfsbl_exit.o ./src/xfsbl_handoff.o ./src/xfsbl_hooks.o ./src/xfsbl_image_header.o ./src/xfsbl_initialization.o ./src/xfsbl_main.o ./src/xfsbl_misc.o ./src/xfsbl_misc_drivers.o ./src/xfsbl_nand.o ./src/xfsbl_partition_load.o ./src/xfsbl_plpartition_valid.o ./src/xfsbl_qspi.o ./src/xfsbl_rsa_sha.o ./src/xfsbl_sd.o ./src/xfsbl_translation_table.o ./src/xfsbl_usb.o   -lhello -Wl,--start-group,-lxil,-lgcc,-lc,--end-group -Wl,--start-group,-lxilffs,-lxil,-lgcc,-lc,--end-group -Wl,--start-group,-lxilsecure,-lxil,-lgcc,-lc,--end-group -Wl,--start-group,-lxilpm,-lxil,-lgcc,-lc,--end-group -n
/tmp/ccjtx6CQ.ltrans0.ltrans.o: In function `main':
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x18c): undefined reference to `dlopen'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x18c): relocation truncated to fit: R_AARCH64_CALL26 against undefined symbol `dlopen'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x19c): undefined reference to `dlsym'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x19c): relocation truncated to fit: R_AARCH64_CALL26 against undefined symbol `dlsym'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x1a4): undefined reference to `library_function'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x1a4): relocation truncated to fit: R_AARCH64_CALL26 against undefined symbol `library_function'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x1ac): undefined reference to `dlclose'
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x1ac): relocation truncated to fit: R_AARCH64_CALL26 against undefined symbol `dlclose'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [fsbl.elf] Error 1
```

Finally my question is how to load -ldl in cross compiling
if i use -ldl in C/C++ Build settings-.libraries->library paths . I am getting error as

```
/wrk/released/2017.3/GA/2017.3_1005_1/installs/lin64/SDK/2017.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-none/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-none-elf/6.2.1/../../../../aarch64-none-elf/bin/ld: cannot find -ldl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [fsbl.elf] Error 1
```

Comment: What operating system will the binary be running on? Knowing the naming conventions of those tools "aarch64-none" kind of implies no operating system. What makes you think that there is a `dl` library at all? "Xilinx SDK" from quick googling seems to be intended to build stuff that runs on bare metal.

Comment: Use `--sysroot` to point to the target's headers and libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Different parts of your answer seem to conflict.

`dlopen`, `dlsym` and friends are used to load code from another **file** on the filesystem. In other words, these functions are related to loading code, at runtime, from a library available on the target platform filesystem and operating system.

In the case of cross compiling, the toolchain needs to provide the library (`libdl.so` or `libdl.a`) that has the implementaiton of those functions. The toolchain provide the code that has the relevant *operating system* calls to open the file with the code, map it to memory and link it into the running program.

Which is where the conflict comes into play. The toolchain you mention seems to be **bare metal** toolchain. In other words, this is a tool chain for running your code directly on the chip, with no operating system. If you have no operating system, it should be obvious that you cannot use it in order to load further code at runtime.

With that in mind, it should be obvious why the tool chain does not supply you with a suitable implementation of `libdl.a`. It cannot be generically implemented on the platform.